# Laravel Blade CSS vanishes as I select edit button to edit form

Tags: html, css, laravel-blade, laravel-9

Below is my layouts.app file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@yield('title', 'Default content') - Touchstone QMS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta content="Premium Multipurpose Admin & Dashboard Template" name="description" />
    <meta content="Themesbrand" name="author" />
    <!-- App favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('assets/images/favicon.ico') }}">

    <!-- jquery.vectormap css -->
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/libs/admin-resources/jquery.vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css') }}"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" id="bootstrap-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Icons Css -->
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/icons.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- App Css-->
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/app.min.css') }}" id="app-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Responsive Table css -->
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/libs/admin-resources/rwd-table/rwd-table.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />

</head>

<body data-layout="detached" data-topbar="colored">



    <!-- <body data-layout="horizontal" data-topbar="dark"> -->

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Begin page -->
        <div id="layout-wrapper">
            <!-- ========== Header Start ========== -->
            @component('components.header')
            @endcomponent
            <!-- Header End -->
            <!-- ========== Left Sidebar Start ========== -->
            @component('components.sidebar')
            @endcomponent
            <!-- Left Sidebar End -->

            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <!-- Start right Content here -->
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="page-content">
                    <!-- start page title -->
                    @include('includes.title')
                    {{-- <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="page-title-box d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <h4 class="page-title mb-0 font-size-18">Dashboard</h4>

            <div class="page-title-right">
                <ol class="breadcrumb m-0">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Welcome to Qovex Dashboard</li>
                </ol>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div> --}}
                    <!-- end page title -->
                    @yield('content')
                </div>
                <!-- End Page-content -->

                <footer class="footer">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <script>
                                    document.write(new Date().getFullYear())
                                </script> © Touchstone Communications.
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="text-sm-end d-none d-sm-block">
                                    Design & Develop by Business Intelligence Department
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
            <!-- end main content-->

        </div>
        <!-- END layout-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- end container-fluid -->

    <!-- Right Sidebar -->
    @component('components.right-sidebar')
    @endcomponent
    <!-- /Right-bar -->

    <!-- Right bar overlay-->
    <div class="rightbar-overlay"></div>

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/libs/metismenu/metisMenu.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/libs/simplebar/simplebar.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/libs/node-waves/waves.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/libs/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- apexcharts -->
    <script src="{{ 'assets/libs/apexcharts/apexcharts.min.js' }}"></script>

    <!-- jquery.vectormap map -->
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/libs/admin-resources/jquery.vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/libs/admin-resources/jquery.vectormap/maps/jquery-jvectormap-us-merc-en.js') }}">
    </script>

    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/pages/dashboard.init.js') }}"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- Responsive Table js -->
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/libs/admin-resources/rwd-table/rwd-table.min.js') }}"></script>
    @yield('scripts')
</body>

</html>
```

In my users.index file when I select users.edit, the page redirects to edit page but my all css and javascript of page wipes up. I have attached an image [The image showing edit page without css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEoTL.jpg). My users.edit blade is:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

@section('title', 'Edit User')

@section('content')

```
<div class="back-area mb-3">
    <a href="{{ route('users.index') }}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left mr-2"></i> Go
        Back</a>
</div>

<!-- Default box -->
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">User Detail</h3>
    </div>

    <form action="{{ route('users.update', $user) }}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">HRMS</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hrms_id" value="{{ $user->hrms_id ?? '' }}"
                    placeholder="Enter HRMS" required>
            </div>
    </form>

</div>
<!-- /.card -->
```

@endsection
Now how can I fix the issue? I have checked all the css and javascript files. They are linked properly. I am using laravel 9.